# Calling a tabbar view controller from a view controller which is already imported by called viewcontroller?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Maybe a stupid question but I have to do it as soon as possible. My problem is:

I have four tabbar controllers `A,B,C,D` and these are imported a viewcontroller (suppose name button controller) at the navigation bar.

So, A,B,C,D are importing this buttonview controller like this `#import buttonViewController.h` in every `.h` file of A,B,C,D `tabbar controller`.

Now problem is, in `buttonViewController` I have a button which action calling the "A" `tabbar controller` or "B", "C",or "D" `tabbar controller`.

I have already added `buttonViewController` in every A,B,C,D `tabbarcontroller`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha ha ha .....it was so much fun when i solved it.whatever i solved this problem in different way, i did not use scrollview button controller for controller just, in every controller i have made function to where buttons within a scrollview create and on action of button i have just change the selected index of the tabbar controller.

in `-(void)viewDidload` i wrote this code

```
     UIView *scrollViewBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
scrollViewBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topmenu_bg.png"]];

menuScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,320,40)];
menuScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
menuScrollView.bounces = TRUE;
[scrollViewBackgroundView addSubview:menuScrollView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollViewBackgroundView];

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(92.0, 30.0) withOffset:5.0f noOfButtons:7];
```

here is the button create and action

```
-(void)mybuttons:(id)sender{    
NSLog(@"mybuttons called");
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);
int m = button.tag;
for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
    if(button.tag == m){
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = m;
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; //sets the background Image]            
    }
    if(button.tag != m){
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]
    }
}
}       

 -(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

NSLog(@"inserting into the function for menu bar button creation"); 
for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(mybuttons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    (button).titleLabel.font =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];
    if(i==0){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dashboard"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]
    }
    if(i==1){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    if(i==2){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Product"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    if(i==3){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Customers"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    if(i==4){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
    }
    if(i==5){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Site Analysis"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    if(i==6){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Store Settings"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    if(i==7){
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CMS Settings"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

    }
    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 6.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
    button.clipsToBounds = YES;
    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5;//half of the width
    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    button.layer.borderWidth=0.0f;
    button.tag=i;
    [menuScrollView addSubview:button];
}
menuScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);
[self.view addSubview:menuScrollView];

}
```